# Open flash in new page

Tags: actionscript-2, flash-cs5

New to Flash and I am working with Flash 5, actionscript 2.

I have the following code,

```
b1.onPress = function()

{getURL("http://rosswarner.com/lion.html");

}
```

I want the page to be opened in a blank page.
I have tried the usual HTML way, no luck, done some looking, no luck so here I am.

Please change the above code to what it has to be if possible.
Thanks.

Comment: Just in case someone else needs the answer, here it is myButton_btn.onRelease=function(){
getURL("http://www.tutorial5.com/", "_blank");
}

Answer (score 0):

By Default GetURL uses the parameter "_self"... you need the parameter "_blank"
You can do this by using

```
getURL("http://rosswarner.com/lion.html";, "_blank");
```

Other parameters include "_parent" and "_top"